# Empty REMOTE_ADDR value in Django application, when using nginx as reverse proxy with gunicorn

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, proxy

I have nginx set up as reverse proxy, with **gunicorn** in the background. This web-server set up feeds my Django app, that has a postgresql backend. The whole set up is hosted on two Ubuntu machines (one's the application machine, other's the DB machine).

I tested this set up solely via gunicorn, without nginx. Worked perfectly. Next to get it up for production, I added the nginx reverse proxy in front of gunicorn. Immediately I ran into a debilitating error: **invalid input syntax for type inet: ""** (comes when a user tries to log into my Django app)

The IPs of users who log into my app are saved in a session table; Django does that on its own. Now it's a known fact that Postgresql requires all client IPs to be of the [INET sort](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/datatype-net-types.html#DATATYPE-INET) (some other DBs allow string IPs too, but not postgres). INET type doesn't allow "" (i.e. empty) values, and instead throws an error **invalid input syntax for type inet: ""**.

In other words, my nginx reverse proxy is not sending the value for `REMOTE_ADDR` to the Django app. Solely using gunicorn correctly sets that value (and hence everything works). How do I get nginx to pass an `$remote_addr` value to `REMOTE_ADDR` in Django's request.META?

I've tried including `proto_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;` in the `location` block in my /etc/nginx/sites-avaialble/myproject file. It does NOT work - I can see a `HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR` value in request.META in the aftermath, but `REMOTE_ADDR` is still ' '. 
[image]

So how do I set REMOTE_ADDR (i.e. the client's IP address) field in Django's request.META? Maybe I can pass it explicitly via gunicorn? Someone mentioned I should handle it at the DB end - I'm not sure how I can do that? Should I edit pg_hba.conf or postgresql.conf or something? I've looked into those files, there's no option to 'allow null values for IPs' to be logged. Moreover, I'd rather pass whatever value resides in $remote_addr to Django, instead of letting all logged in users' IPs be null.

And let's not forget that if I use *solely* gunicorn, REMOTE_ADDR in Django's request.META gets correctly set; so my guess is the problem lies with how I'm passing it via nginx.

Please help! And feel free to ask for more information if you feel you need it.

---

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.cloudapp.net;
    charset utf-8;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {

        root /home/mhb11/folder/myproject;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass          http://unix:/home/mhb11/folder/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }


    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/mhb11/folder/myproject/templates/;
   }
}
```

/etc/nginx/proxy_params:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header User-Agent $http_user_agent;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Comment: Could you try to change `proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;` to `proxy_set_header REMOTE-ADDR $remote_addr;`?

Comment: Gave it a shot, unfortunately results in exactly the same thing. I tried that earlier too, thinking the correct syntax is probably to use a hyphen instead of an underscore, like every directive. Doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to explicitly pass this via gunicorn? If one can pass secure_scheme_headers: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/19.3/settings.html#secure-scheme-headers, perhaps one can pass a value for REMOTE_ADDR too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known issue. Check out this discussion around REMOTE_ADDR being invalid when running a domain socket server: https://github.com/python-web-sig/wsgi-ng/issues/11

The one thing you can do to ensure all dependencies remain intact is write middleware that takes care of your problem at the Django project level.

For instance, something like this:

```
class XForwardedForMiddleware():
    def process_request(self, request):
        if "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" in request.META:
            request.META["HTTP_X_PROXY_REMOTE_ADDR"] = request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"]
            parts = request.META["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].split(",", 1)
            request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"] = parts[0]
```

([source](http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-ip-address-behind-nginx-proxy.html))

Try it, it's surely going to solve your problem.

Comment: `.has_key()` doesn't exist in Python3 but `if "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" in request.META` did the trick. This fixed my issue, thanks!

Comment: 9 years later and still an issue? why isn't this implemented in debug_toolbar

Comment: Not that this has a security risk. The HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can easily be spoofed, and anyone can pass a random IP in the header, and your application will think it's real. Instead, we can use the X-Real-IP header, which contains remote_addr.

Answer (score 1):

I was having some minor issues with the provided solution. In some cases, for some bots, the value actually contained 'unknown' as the first entry. So I had to tweak it to look at all the values, taking the first valid one as the `REMOTE_ADDR`.

```
class XForwardedForMiddleware:
    """
    Set REMOTE_ADDR if it's missing because of a reverse proxy (nginx + gunicorn) deployment.
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251298/empty-remote-addr-value-in-django-application-when-using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy
    """
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' in request.META:
            remote_addrs = request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].split(',')
            remote_addr = None

            # for some bots, 'unknown' was prepended as the first value: `unknown, ***.***.***.***`
            # in which case the second value actually is the correct one
            for ip in remote_addrs:
                ip = self._validated_ip(ip)
                if ip is not None:
                    remote_addr = ip
                    break

            if remote_addr is None:
                raise SuspiciousOperation('Malformed X-Forwarded-For.')

            request.META['HTTP_X_PROXY_REMOTE_ADDR'] = request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']
            request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'] = remote_addr

        return self.get_response(request)

    def _validated_ip(self, ip):
        ip = ip.strip()
        try:
            validate_ipv46_address(ip)
        except ValidationError:
            return None
        return ip
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with the following code。

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin


class XForwardedForMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" in request.META:
            request.META["REMOTE_ADDR"] = request.META["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ip_address = request.META.get("HTTP_X_REAL_IP")
```

It works with Django versions greater than 3.

Comment: add version to which this applies because its a very old question. EoR.